# Why does Oxford American English dictionary use "y" symbol instead of "j"

Tags: pronunciation, writing-style, ipa, american-english

Oxford American English dictionary uses "y" symbol instead of "j" in their pronunciation guide. Most other dictionaries use j. So are there any differences between the 2 symbols or they are just the same? Why do they have to use y instead of j?

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english

Cambridge dictionaries use j in yes pronunciation transcription: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/yes?q=Yes

Oxford American English dictionary uses y: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/yes_1?q=Yes

Comment: **/dʒ/** as in  /dʒun/ is the most common phonetic symbol for **J**. Where are you seeing "y" being used to represent the consonant J?

Comment: Please see the link I mentioned, y is used as a consonant symbol https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english

Comment: I *did* look at it, and I didn't see where the letter "J" is represented by the letter "y". Can you quote the example?  I actually quoted the example June from the same page. For the letter "Y" it has:  y yes **/yɛs/**

Comment: But in other dictionaries, yes is pronounced /jɛs/. So can I say y and j are the same?

Comment: Then you need to edit and provide a link to one or more dictionaries where the /j/ symbol is used to represent *y* in *yes*.  Your question is quite misleading :)

Comment: Cambridge dictionaries and most of other dictionaries use j, including Oxford English/Academic dictionary. j is very common, I thought everyone knew. Just wonder why Oxford American English dictionary uses y https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/yes?q=Yes

Comment: Because American English phonemes are not the same symbols as UK English phonemes. The European standard (IPA) is /j/, but American English phonemes use the Y symbol instead of J. J is in fact not used in American English phonemics; Y is used instead. There are no /y/ vowels in English, so there's no confusion, unless one expects UK and US Englishes to be pronounced the same.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Obviously soomeone like *you* wouldn't be confused! But I'm not that familiar with IPA in the first place, nor was I aware of this particular US/UK "usage split". And even though I don't expect UK and US Englishes to be pronounced the same *in general*, I ***do*** assume the initial consonant in ***Yes*** is articulated "the same" by all Anglophones. (Though on reflection I won't fall off my perch if you tell me that expert ears and speech analysis hardware / software can differentiate even that! :)

Comment: But the phonemic symbols for English are not phonetic symbols -- they're phonemes, not phones, and the IPA is specifically only for phones. When someone uses the term "phonemic", you're sposta understand that it's a local language-specific bunch of characters, not strict IPA. So what you expect is wrong. Get used to it.

Comment: Also, note that lots of languages with j's in their alphabets pronounce them differently-our j is almost always a  'dʒ,' the german j is like our y, the Spanish j is like an h, the french is a ʒ, etc.

Comment: @Heartspring No, the Spanish ‹j› grapheme is the /x/ phoneme, typically [x] and sometimes [χ]. It is a typical American mishearing of sounds they do not understand to call it [h] when it is not.  [*Véase esto, por favor*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Sonidos_conson%C3%A1nticos).

Comment: [On transcription, broad or narrow with salt](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/301/when-should-one-use-slashes-or-square-brackets-when-transcribing-in-ipa/304#304)

Comment: @tchrist- Fair enough. I actually never noticed that difference, at least not consciously. I started learning Spanish when I was like 3, and did find out about the IPA until I was older. Having read your comment and seen the table, I can sort of hear that difference. Siempre los pronunciaba diferente pero los pensaba igual; gracias para informarme.

Answer (score 1):

/j/ is correct in the [International Phonetic Alphabet (see Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

However, this tends to cause great confusion for English speakers, who pronounce the letter "j" in most words as /dʒ/; they might think that the dictionary intended a /dʒ/ sound when they see /j/ in a pronunciation.

So some dictionaries will try to avoid the problem by using "y" instead of /j/. This is rather annoying, since the IPA *already* uses /y/ to indicate a particular vowel sound ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel)). But that sound does not generally appear in English, so English dictionaries can get away with using "y" to represent the /j/ sound.

Comment: Phonemes do not represent literal sounds. This is a great confusion. **Only phones are literal sounds, and dictionaries only ever give phonemes and therefore *dictionaries never actually tell you the exact sounds.*** You always have to convert to the phones that make sense in the phonology of the local dialect's accent and context and speaker and utterance.  Just look at /r/ if you don't believe me. Phonemics won't give you sounds by themselves. The [r] phone does not occur in American English. Ever. **When the Oxford American English Dictionary writes /r/, they *never* mean [r]!**